# LINQ join return datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I would like to know if it is possible to return a datatable by joining two datatables.

```
var query = from v in dt1.AsEnumerable()
      join c in dt2.AsEnumerable() on v.Field<int>("ID") equals c.Field<int>("ID")
      where v.Field<string>("col1").Equals("abcd") 
      && (c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8776") || c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8775"))
      select new 
{};
```

I have joined two datatables with various conditions. Is it possible to return a datatable from them with all the rows from both the datatable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can return an anonymous object if the query is going to be evaluated right away, and you don't need to pass it through as a return type nor an argument type of some method.

```
var query = from v in dt1.AsEnumerable()
      join c in dt2.AsEnumerable() on v.Field<int>("ID") equals c.Field<int>("ID")
      where v.Field<string>("col1").Equals("abcd") 
      && (c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8776") || c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8775"))
      select new  { v, c };
```

And then:

```
foreach (var result in query) {
    var v = result.v;
    var c = result.c;
    // do your magic here
}
```

If that's not the case, you can always create a simple struct with the 2 fields, one for each table row.

Comment: I want to have some more filtration using LINQ on the basis of data I get in the first query. I cannot use LINQ in your above solution.

Comment: You can continue filtering the joined rows before the `select`